# Am I writing out too much data to a page with a javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I am trying to build a subnet calculator as my own personal project to learn programming.  The part I am having an issue with is I would like to present classful subnet ranges, example 172.16.1.1/30 would present 16384 subnets...
172.16.0.0 - 172.16.0.3
172.16.0.4 - 172.16.0.7
172.16.0.8 - 172.16.0.11
... etc.

So when I write it out to a website, it locks up the browser for a few seconds and takes longer than I think it should.  I researched as much as I could and I found entering entering 'setTimeout' will help with the locking up and handles the ClassB subnets (maxing out at 65536 with /32).  However when I go into the hundreds of thousands and millions I still have issues.  I created a test script to play with numbers and see what works.  Being very new to this I am out of ideas.  Here is my test code...

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Page</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="subnetRange" style="border : solid 2px #ff0000; background : #000000; color : #ffffff; padding : 4px; width : 250px; height : 350px; overflow : auto; "></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="pump.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var i = 0;
var myArray = new Array();
document.getElementById('subnetRange').innerHTML = "Loading...";   //carry on pumping?

function doCalculation()
{

   //Surrounding loop to break the time out up by 1000 increments
   for ( var x = 0; x < 2000; x++) {
     myArray[i] = i;
     i = i + 1;
     var percent_complete=i;
   }

   return percent_complete;
}

function pump()
{
   var percent_complete=doCalculation();
   if (percent_complete<100000)
   {
      //pump();
      setTimeout(pump, 1);
   }
   if (percent_complete >= 100000) {
      document.getElementById('subnetRange').innerHTML = myArray.join("<br />");   //carry on pumping?
   }
}


//setTimeout(pump, 1);
pump();
```

I hope I have giving enough information to help out.  If not please ask and I will give you information to the best of my ability.

Thank you

Comment: Looks interesting, can you post a live demo?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you are splitting up your (light) `doCalculation` calls into very small async chunks and then do the (heavy) writing of 100000 lines to the DOM at once?

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing.  Is there a way to write it out a little bit at a time but also make it very fast.  I saw a demo of 5000 lines being written out but it took quite a while.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/EmbraceNext/xYxqa/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're splitting the computation of `doCalculation` in chunks of 2000, but then once the array has a length of 100000 you do

> ```
> document.getElementById('subnetRange').innerHTML = myArray.join("<br />");
> ```

That's the wrong way round. Not filling an array is the heavy work (that happens in sub-milliseconds), but the DOM manipulation. You need to take that apart, for example like this:

```
function pump() {
    var oldItemCount = myArray.length;
    var percent_complete = doCalculation();
    var newItems = myArray.slice(oldItemCount);
    document.getElementById('subnetRange').innerHTML += newItems.join("<br />");
    //                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (percent_complete < 100000) {
        setTimeout(pump, 1);
    }
}
```

([updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xYxqa/4/))

Notice the code above is only for understanding the issue, further improvements could be made: `newItems` could be the return value of `doCalculation`, the slicing would become unnecessary then. And the `innerHTML +=` might actually slow down older browsers which cannot optimize this (they serialize the DOM, do the string concatenation, and parse the huge HTML string again). You may need to find a better way to append small chunks of DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes miliseconds... maybe increase it from 1 to like 25 or 35?

```
setTimeout(pump, 35);
```

Comment: It still causes the browser to lock up when going over 100000 loops the way I have it written.  Now the browser is Firefox.  It works better in chrome.  I would like it to work well in all (current) browsers though.